# Swift dictionary wrong access

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the email value from an Author struct stored in a dictionary. Here some code and you can see that if I'm trying to get it from the dictionary it is not working. 
Any idea why?

```
struct Author{
    var name: String
    var email: String
}

var dict_author = [String: Author]()

var aut1 = Author(name: "Author1", email: "a1@gmail.com")

dict_author["Author1"] = aut1 

var a = dict_author["Author1"]

println(a.email) //not working
println(aut1.email) // a1@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dictionary lookup always returns an optional, so you have to unwrap it before using:

```
println(a?.email)
```

Suggested reading: [Optionals](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_483) and [Dictionaries](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_180)

Comment: Thanks, I totally missed this part !